# Swedish Keyboard with ubuntu? Just adding layout does not work!

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, 16.10

I have recently installed Ubuntu 16.10 on my old laptop and I was wondering how I can change to a Swedish keyboard. I chose Swedish keyboard during Ubuntu installation but it did not work with the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd> keys that Swedish keyboards have.
So for example, if I wanna make an '@' symbol (or if I want to get in to my email) then i need to change to my English keyboard layout. I also do a lot of programming and whenever I need to make a '{', Well I can't. Why is this? How can I fix it so I can use a Swedish keyboard with Ubuntu?

Comment: You need the <AltGr> key to type the characters you mention with the Swedish layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a driver for your hardware is missing.

I was testing Lubuntu 16.10 during the development until it was released. All this time I was installing it 'in Swedish', and it worked for me. Standard Ubuntu also works with Swedish text and Swedish keyboard. For example, I get **@** with <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> and I get **{** with <kbd>AltGr</kbd>  + <kbd>7</kbd>. If this does not work for you, I suspect that you have some special keyboard (or special computer).

Please tell us about your computer and keyboard (brand names and models). With that information someone who reads this might recognize your problem and suggest a solution for 16.10.

Comment: I did not know that Altgr worked. And i am prutty sure that is the only way i will get it to work. Thx.

Comment: You are welcome :-) You can use the program *onboard* to 'see' what characters you get with *AltGr* and other keys.

Comment: I fail to understand how downgrading to 16.04 would make a difference in this case, and the general discussion on LTS vs. non-LTS is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: My idea was that maybe the keyboard was some special model, that was not supported by 16.10. But obviously it was not, and maybe my idea was bad. Anyway, I can remove that part of the text, because I don't want to cause any confusion.

Comment: Saw that you removed it, which I think was good. I removed my downvote. ;) (xkb-data is very similar in 16.04 and 16.10.)